# Подскажите, как передать http.client в функцию

Tags: http, golang

Я только начал изучать go. И появилась реальная задача...

Есть небольшая программа, которая берет адреса файлов из списка и скачивает их. Всё происходит в go-рутинах, т.е., многопоточно.

Там всё довольно просто - просто делается http.Get и тело сохраняется в файл.

Проблема в том, что не все сервера отвечают быстро и иногда отваливаются по таймауту при попытке соединения.

```
dial tcp адрес:443: i/o timeout
```

Подумал, в основном потоке сделать так:

```
client := http.Client {
    Timeout: 20 * time.Second,
}
```

И в рутине делать client.Get, но как передать client в рутину? Полагаю, как указатель, но какой будет тип параметра функции?
Простите, если вопрос слишком простой. Нагуглить не получилось...

Или может можно http.DefaultClient изменить, по аналогии с этим:

```
http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).TLSClientConfig = &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если делать так:

```
client := &http.Client {
    Timeout: 20 * time.Second,
}
```

То тип будет *http.Client.